# How can I save a Facebook thread with all posts and images in a mobile friendly format?

Tags: facebook

I want to **save** some specific **Facebook post** to later offline browsing.

**Requirements:**

- Maintain question/answer **structure**.
- Save **images** at full resolution, not only thumbnails.
- The final format must be comfortable to **browse on mobile devices**. Ideal case would be just the same appearance that can be found by online browsing Facebook site.
- **Only conversations** are needed. The side banners and other stuff could be ignored.

What is the best **method or program** that can do this?

Comment: If you want to spend some time coding, I don't think it would be that hard to write a script that did it based on css.

Comment: @klutt I think that would be hard, very hard. The page contents is highly obfuscated. Try hitting ^U (View Source) on any fb page, it's a nightmare. Also scrolling is implemented procedurally generated, so the code updates the contents as you scroll, it's not all in there at once.